# jQuery AJAX request not firing when posting to a php script.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a database table which I am trying to retrieve data from using JQUERY AJAX. When my first page loads it does a php call to a table and populates a select form element. - This works
I then want to select one of the options submit the form and have the row returned via Ajax. 
Previously I had the script working with just PHP files but am having trouble getting it to work. When submitting the form my URL is changing:

```
http://localhost/FINTAN/testertester.php?name=Specifics.
```

I am not getting anything back. In addition when looking at my console I get a jquery not defined 
factory (jquery). I can find the line in question in my jquery ui.js. Not sure if this is the issue or my code has caused the issue. I have cleard the firefox cache and due to the fact I have not had a successful AJAX call via jquery method am guessing it my code.

To get the code below I have mixed and matched a book and an online tutorial and many other sources and this is not my first attempt. Ideally I would like to output table row. However just getting a request working and knowing its not  a conflict or compatability issue would makeme feel better and not hindered before I start

```
   <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#btn").click(function(){
           var vname = $("#name").val;
       } 
   }
   $.post("addithandle1.php",
   {
       name:vname};

   function(response,status){   
       alert("recieved data-------*\n\nResponse : " + response 
               +"\n\nStatus : " + status);
   }
   }
   </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <?php
include "config.php";

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{

}
else
{
  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM script ");



     echo " <Form  method='post'> <label>Script :</label> <select id='name'  name='name' >";
}
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {   

    echo "<option value = '".$row['scriptname']."'>".$row['scriptname']."</option>"; 
    } 
  echo "</select>";  
           echo "<button id='btn'  class='btn-search'>Load Script </button></form>";     
?>
</body></html>
```

This is my PHP file that I am trying to retrieve from

```
 <?php
include 'config.php';

$batchtype2 = $_POST['name'];


$batchtype2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$batchtype2);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM script WHERE scriptname  = '".$batchtype2."' ";       


$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==0 ){
    echo "</br></br></br></br></br></br></br><p> No Matching results found</p>";
}

else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo '<tr><td>'.$row['scriptname'].'</td></tr>';
  echo '<tr><td>'.$row['scripthours'].'</td></tr>';
   echo '<tr><td>'.$row['scripttotal'].'</td></tr>';


 }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You're trying to set the parameter using GET  (http://localhost/FINTAN/testertester.php?name=Specifics), but you're trying to get the value using the $_POST super global.

Comment: No he's not trying to set $_GET, he's trying ajax but because he's not preventing the default form submit the form also gets submitted and generates a url with the params in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making the following corrections (you have some syntax issues as well as usage issues which should be revealed in your browser's console when you load this page) in your JavaScript/jQuery this will work like you expect -

Make sure to change this line -

```
var vname = $("#name").val;
```

to this -

```
var vname = $("#name").val(); // note the parentheses
```

in your function -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action of the click
           var vname = $("#name").val();
           $.post("addithandle1.php", {name:vname}, function(response, status) { // POST instead of GET
               // never use alert() for troubleshooting
               // output for AJAX must be in the callback for the AJAX function
               console.log("recieved data-------*\n\nResponse : " + response +"\n\nStatus : " + status);
               $('#table').html(response); // put response in div
        });
    });
});
```

Now `$_POST['name']` should get populated properly.

To get the table to appear in your requesting page first make sure that your PHP forms the table completely.

Add a `div` to your requesting page and modify the AJAX call above as shown.

```
<div id="table"></div>
```

Now, when you make a request the `div` on the requesting page will be updated with whatever comes back from the PHP script.

Comment: I put in  var vname = $("#name option:selected" ).text(); instead of .val() nd I am getting a response (desired one) in the console. The thing is the option value and text are the same php echo? I can still work with this. If I want to place the response text in to my page flow to I have to grab an element ('#element').html(respons).text ?

Comment: I see this now Jay. Was wondering why the selected option was working!

Comment: You have been so helpful already! But how to I transfer this to my page from log?

Comment: Jay - I can not thank you enough. I have been searching for a solution for this problem for a couple of days now round family duties/work and was about to settle for the working less pleasing PHP solution. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things about your script.

First make sure you write well structured code and that it is nothing in the wrongplace / broken.

You have in the $(document).ready(function(){ only the .click event of the button, but you left the ajax request outside, I imagine you did that so it will also make the ajax request in the first page load

The problem is that now it will only make it in the first page load, but not when you click the button, on clicking button you are only getting the value of name.

I recommend you to try something like this:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind button click and load data
   $("#btn").click(function(){
       loadData();
       return false; // prevent browser behaviour of the button that would submit the form
   }
   // load data for the first time
   loadData();
};

function loadData() {
    var vname = $("#name").val;
    $.post("addithandle1.php", { name:vname }, function(response, status) {
       alert("recieved data-------*\n\nResponse : " + response 
               +"\n\nStatus : " + status);
    });
}

</script>
```

A few notes:

- I would recommend always putting jquery code inside $(document).ready since that guarantees that jquery was loaded before running it
- By default a form that has a submit button that you click, will get the form submitted by the browser, if you use ajax, you should prevent that behaviour, either on the button click event or on form with onsubmit="return false".

Comment: Small correction @Alexandru - the document ready handler makes sure the DOM is completely loaded before jQuery acts on it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Jay, did not realize that, I just know it is important to place the code there in order to have jquery and html interact correctly, did not know the exact thing happening behind that :)